# how to design superscript in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to display how many items are there in cart. on top of the cart symbol. but I'm facing an issue using grid layout. since, nativescript wont support superscript. is there any better way to design.

i tried something like below. but the number of items is not properly displaying on top right of the cart symbol.

```
 <GridLayout col="2" rows="auto" columns="*,*">
                <Label col="0" text="&#xf07a;" fontSize="28" class="fas" textWrap="true" />
                <Label col="1" text="{{ line_item_no }}" fontSize="10" textWrap="true" margin="0 5 0 5" class="fcw" />
            </GridLayout>
```

i need a cart symbol of 25 font size. on top right i need a 10 font size number surrounded by a round background. kindly give me some ideas.

Comment: It's all about positioning, you may use FormattedString Or set appropriate value on `verticalAlginemnt` / `horizontalAlignment` to position the item in X / Y axis.

Comment: @Manoj Formatted string was not working as the text will come to midlle when size was decreased. i didn't get another option what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-decoration: line-through;` property, see the references below:

[https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/*ui_enums*.textdecoration](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_enums_.textdecoration)
https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling

[image]